# For what x does $P_c(x) = \sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^{n+1}\cdot n\cdot x^n$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, exponential-sum

> For what x does the exponential series $P_c(x) = \sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^{n+1}\cdot n\cdot x^n$ converge?

**What I got so far:**

$\sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^{n+1}\cdot n\cdot x^n  = (-1)\sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^{n}\cdot (\sqrt[n]n)^n\cdot x^n = (-1)\sum^\infty_{n=0} ((-1)\cdot (\sqrt[n]n)\cdot x)^n$

We know that $|((-1)\cdot (\sqrt[n]n)\cdot x)|$ must be < 1 in order to converge *(geometric sum)*:

$ |((-1)\cdot (\sqrt[n]n)\cdot x)| < 1$

Case 1: 
$ ((-1)\cdot (\sqrt[n]n)\cdot x) < 1 \Leftrightarrow (-1)\cdot (\sqrt[n]n)\cdot x < 1 \Leftrightarrow (-1)\cdot x < \frac{1}{(\sqrt[n]n)} \Leftrightarrow x > \frac{-1}{(\sqrt[n]n)}$

Case 2:
$ ((\sqrt[n]n)\cdot x) < 1 \Leftrightarrow (\sqrt[n]n)\cdot x < 1 \Leftrightarrow x < \frac{1}{(\sqrt[n]n)}$

We know that $x < |\frac{-1}{(\sqrt[n]n)}| = |\frac{1}{(\sqrt[n]n)}| = \frac{1}{(\sqrt[n]n)} \le \pm 1 $

So $x < (-1) < 1$. **Is this way right**, must $x$ be $< -1$ in order for $P_c(x) $ to converge? Is there a simpler way to get to a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DonAntonio was a typo, was supposed to be cancelled out like $(\sqrt[n])^n$

Comment: "We know that $|((-1)\cdot (\sqrt[n]n)\cdot x)^n|$ must be $< 1$ in order to converge" ...we do? From where or why?

Comment: @DonAntonio For $|((-1)\cdot (\sqrt[n]n \cdot x)| < 1$ $ P_c(x)$ converges, because of the geometric sum, sry the $()^n$ was another and hopefully the last typo

Comment: Perhaps you meant that if $\;|((-1)\sqrt[n]nx|=q<1\;$ then, comparing with a geometric series, yours then converges....but I think you're confusing things here: you have here **a power series**, and its radius of convergence in uniquely determined by the sequence of coefficients of $\;x^n\;$...

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean. Solving that equation for x gives us every (geometric) series that converges, doesn't it?

Comment: @Wh No, it doesn't, as you get inqualities for $\;x\;$ *depending on* $\;n\;$ , which is a running index...

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, x depends on the runnning index n, but $\sqrt[n]n$ has the limit $1$. So at some point it doesnt affect the term $|(-1)\sqrt[n]n\cdot x|$ anymore at which point only the x decides whether the series converges or not. I tested the inequality by setting in the results of bose cases above: (1) $(-1)\sqrt[n]n\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]n}$ = harmonic series, (2) $(-1) \cdot \sqrt[n]n \frac{-1}{\sqrt[n]n}$ = 1 (series obviously doesn't converge)

Comment: @W Do as you please.

Comment: @DonAntonio wow

Comment: Well thanks for your efforts up to this point

Answer (score 2):

Cauchy-Hadamard:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|(-1)^{n+1}n\right|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n=1$$

so the series converges for $\;|x|<1\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

May be, you could consider that $$\sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^{n+1} n x^n=x\sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^{n+1} n x^{n-1}=x \frac{d}{dx} \left(\sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^{n+1} x^n \right)=-x\frac{d}{dx} \left(\sum^\infty_{n=0} (-x)^{n} \right)$$ Now, in brackets, you have a simple geometric sum easy to compute (and analyze, for sure).

Comment: That is the main argument I used if im not mistaken

Comment: Adaptating John 14:2, "*Mathematics house has many rooms*"